# Sum and Average in multi-dimentional arrays with php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get sum and average of visitors from the following multi-dimensional array :

```
Array([visitors] => Array(
[2015-06-12] => Array([0] => Array([value] => 29))
[2015-06-11] => Array([0] => Array([value] => 55))
...
))
```

I cannot manage to find a way to get the results i need as i get lost with "foreach".

Can anybody help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<?php

$mainarray = array('visitors' => Array(
        '2015-06-12' => Array(Array('value' => 29)),
        '2015-06-11' => Array(Array('value' => 55))));
$sum = 0;
$count = 0;

$visitor =  $mainarray['visitors'];
foreach ($visitor as $key => $val) {
    $sum += $val[0]['value'];
    $count++;
}
echo "Sum is " . $sum."<br>";
$average = ($sum / $count);
echo "Average is " .$average."<br>";;
?>
```

Comment: Think again about structure

Comment: I did think. Not helped :)

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks @FaizRasool and splash58 !

Comment: @BastienBastiens i'm happy to help you:) just vote up :)